# Is there any way to identify if chrome toolbar is enabled from a chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and it requires to inject an HTML file into a web-page if the extensions tool bar is disabled. Is there any way to check whether the extension tool bar is enabled from my chrome extension?

Comment: No. You can suggest it to developers on https://crbug.com

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "tool bar is disabled"?

Comment: I meant the tool-bar with the extensions and bookmark. I got it. Just check the window.toolbar